# How to stop frozen bananas making everything else in the freezer taste like banana?

Tags: freezing, bananas

I freeze peeled bananas for making ice cream. I triple bag them in three Ziploc bags. This works fine.

However, apparently they are making other things in the freezer taste like bananas.

Apart from even more bags, does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: I keep my bananas in a bag in the freezer they don't make everything taste like bananas but in your case I'd suggest a metal/glass container if your tripple bagging isn't enough.

Answer (score 4):

Use about 3-4 boxes of Arm and Hammer Baking Soda, one on each shelf in the freezer and use better sealing freezer bags and not ziplock. I would suggest a machine that heat seals them. Good luck!

Comment: -1, despite the old myth, baking soda does not magically absorb odors.

Answer (score 1):

Although it surprises me a bit that three bags are not enough, Ziploc bags do in fact *not* form an absolutely gas tight seal. If you have the means, you can try vacuum-sealing the bananas, or pack them in a container that actually has a proper seal/gasket.

If this still does not help, try packing them in a glass or metal container (again, with a positive seal), as Halhex mentioned in his comment. Although the diffusion of the fragrant compounds through plastic should be sufficiently slow at freezer temperatures.